# Calculation using observableArray in knockoutjs

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js

In my view model there's a observableArray called **projectLine** . This array consist of projectsWorked objects. I need to get the sum of projectsWorked.projectHourWork in the array. I wrote **calcTotal()** to calculate total.

```
  function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        this.CheckIn = ko.observable();
        this.CheckOut = ko.observable();
        this.Lunch = ko.observable();
        this.projectLine = ko.observableArray([new projectsWorked()]);

        this.TimeForWork = ko.computed(function () {
            return this.CheckIn() ? this.CheckOut() ? parseFloat(this.Lunch()) ? parseFloat(this.CheckOut()) - parseFloat(this.CheckIn()) - parseFloat(this.Lunch()) : parseFloat(this.CheckOut()) - parseFloat(this.CheckIn()) : 0 : 0;
        }, this);

        this.Rest = ko.observable();

        this.RemainHour = ko.computed(function () {
            return self.TimeForWork() ? self.Rest() ? self.WorkOnProject() ? parseFloat(self.TimeForWork()) - parseFloat(self.Rest()) - parseFloat(self.WorkOnProject()) : parseFloat(self.TimeForWork()) - parseFloat(self.Rest()) : parseFloat(self.TimeForWork()) : 0
        }, this);

        this.WorkOnProject = ko.observable();
        this.grandTotal = ko.observable();

        this.AddLine = function () {
            alert('hello Add');

            this.calcTotal();
            this.projectLine.push(new projectsWorked());
        };

      //Problem Occurs in here
       this.calcTotal = function () {
           var total = 0;
           alert('ABC');
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.projectLine(), function () {
                alert('BB');
                alert(self.projectLine.projectWork);
                total += self.projectLine.projectHourWork;
            })
                //$.each(self.projectLine, function () {
                //    totalh = parseFloat($('#txthour').val());


                //    total += totalh;
                //    alert(total);
                //})
                this.grandTotal = total;
           //     alert(total);
        }

    };

    function projectsWorked() {
        var self = this;
        this.projectEnable = ko.observable(false);
        this.hours = ko.observable();
        this.projectHourWork=ko.computed(function () {
            return this.hours();
            }, this);

        this.selectedProject = ko.observable();

        this.removeLine = function (line) {
            alert('hello Remove');     
            self.projectLine.removeLine(this);
        };
    };

    var data = [
        "ABC","CDE"
    ];   


    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

But this calculation gives me incorrect value. Firebug shows me self.projectLine.projectHourWork value as undefined. What can be the reason for this? How can I calculate total?

Comment: Why did you declare variable `var self = this;` and then you went on to use `this` instead of `self`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In calcTotal function you refer to self.projectLine in line
 total += self.projectLine.projectHourWork;

self.projectLine is an observableArray so I am pretty sure that projectHourWork is not defined on self.projectLine.

May be this is what you want to do :

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.projectLine(), function (pl) {
    alert('BB');
    total += pl.projectHourWork();
})
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: wat object do u refer by pl?

Comment: pl is an instance of projectsWorked, It s an item of self.projectLine()

Comment: it need to change as `total += project.projectHourWork();` then its working

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the way you loop on your projectLine array.

Inside the loop "self" is a reference to your view model object not to each element of the array. Try something like thi:

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.projectLine(), function (project) {
    alert(project.projectWork);
    total += project.projectHourWork();
});
```

Comment: wat object do u  refer by project?

Comment: it need to change as `total += project.projectHourWork();` then its working

Comment: ko.utils.arryForEach() will call the function you pass as the second parameter for each item in the collection passed as the first parameter, passing the item as a parameter. So "project" will refer to each item in the projectLine array.

Comment: you are correct when adding to the totals project.projectHourWork() is needed since project.projectHourWork is a ko.computed - which is a function.